# Comparing a variable with a string python not working when redirecting from bash script

Tags: python, bash, shell

First I'll show you both the bash and python script (both are in the `/bin` directory on my mac):

The bash script (`esh_1`):

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -n "Enter bash or natural-language command: "
read INPUT
echo $INPUT > ~/USER_INPUT.txt
$INPUT
if (( $? )); then echo Redirected to Python Script; esh_2; cat ~/USER_INPUT.txt; else echo Did not redirect to Python Script;  fi
esh_1
```

The python script (`esh_2`):

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

with open('/Users/bendowling/USER_INPUT.txt', 'r') as UserInputFile:
    UserInput = UserInputFile.read()

UserInputFile = open('/Users/bendowling/USER_INPUT.txt', 'w+')

if UserInput == 'List contents':
    UserInputFile.write("ls")
else:
    print "Didn't work"

UserInputFile.close()
```

The bash script takes the user's input, stores it in a temporary file called `USER_INPUT.txt`, and checks if it runs correctly. If it doesn't, it calls `esh_2` (the python script) which reads the `USER_INPUT.txt` file, taking the user's input. It then checks if it's equal to the string `"List contents"`. If it is, then it writes `"ls"` to the text file. It then closes the file. The bash file then cats the command stored in the text file (in the future I will make it run it as a command). The script then starts again.

The problem is that when I enter `"List contents"` into the shell, it doesn't work, thus printing `"Didn't work"`. However, if I go into the text file myself and write `"List contents"`, the python script works and writes `"ls"` to the text file. I have no clue why this is happening. I would gladly appreciate any help on this matter.

Thanks,
b3n

Comment: Just FYI if you don't want to post your real name, I would replace the pathname with /users/*NAME*/USER_INPUT.txt or something like that (I mean in your post, not in the actual code)

Comment: Before running the Python script, have you checked to see if there is list contents written to the file? That can narrow the problem to either in your bash script or in your python script

Comment: Yes, I did that and knew the problem was in the python script.

Comment: Oh and I don't care about hiding my name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `read()` the file, you may get a newline character `'\n'` in your string. Try either

```
if UserInput.strip() == 'List contents':
```

or

```
if 'List contents' in UserInput:
```

Also note that your second file `open` could also use `with`:

```
with open('/Users/.../USER_INPUT.txt', 'w+') as UserInputFile:
    if UserInput.strip() == 'List contents': # or if s in f:
        UserInputFile.write("ls")
    else:
        print "Didn't work"
```